# Laravel 8 I got problem with the seeding data Seeding: Call to undefined method ::factory()

Tags: php, factory, laravel-8

Goods Factory

```
    public function definition()
{
    return [
        'user_id'=>rand(1,100),
        'title'=>$this->faker->text(30),
        'body'=>$this->faker->text(30),

    ];
}
```

}
Goods Model

```
        Schema::create('goods', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->text('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
```

GoodsTableSeeder

```
public function run()
{
 DB::table('goods')->factory()->times(50)->create();
}
```

**Database\Seeders\GoodsTableSeeder  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::factory()**

Comment: The documentation on [Using Model Factories](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding#using-model-factories) didn't help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few quick guidelines to make factories work in laravel 8.x

1. Declare $model property in your Goods Factory Class:

`protected $model = Goods::class;`

2. Use the `HasFactory` trait in your Goods model class

`use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;`

3. Use factory() method over model class to generate model instance or seed the database:

`Good::factory()->count(15)->create();`

4. If you are using seeders make sure you rename directory `database/seeds` to `database/seeders` and change autoloading as below in `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
```

Laravel 8.x has changed the way of using factories, for more details you can read the documentation as below:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#model-factories
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#defining-model-factories

I hope the above will help you, Feel free to ask if anything not clear.

Comment: Evetything is working!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks a lot !